# Autolayout in Ipad shows a black area with nothing

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, autolayout, scrollview

I am correcting my ipad autolayout and I get this black area and can't find the reason as to why this might be! I've got a scroll view, but I've already placed I think all my constraints. Could someone help me out?

[image: This is what my ipad looks like]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to change view.backgroundColor to white

Comment: I just tried it, and it still looks that way :/

Comment: This problem could be caused by many reasons. This black background may be your scrollviews's background color. Give us more context to help.